# Are the APACHE scores available somewhere?

Tags: mimic-iii

I wonder whether [APACHE scores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APACHE_II) are available somewhere in MIMIC-III.

There doesn't seem to be any widely used APACHE ITEMIDs in the table `CHARTEVENTS`:

```
 SELECT LABEL,  COUNT(*) cnt
 FROM  mimiciii.CHARTEVENTS,
 mimiciii.d_items
  WHERE LOWER(d_items.LABEL) LIKE '%apache%'
  and CHARTEVENTS.itemid = d_items.itemid
   GROUP BY d_items.LABEL
 ORDER BY cnt DESC ;
```

[image]

Comment: A [similar question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6748/mimic-iii-severity-score) has also been posted that asks about severity scores more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Acute Physiology and Chronic Health Evaluation" (APACHE) scores are rarely recorded by caregivers, so they are not well documented in the core MIMIC dataset.

Several APACHE-related `itemid`s appear in the d_items table, as shown in the question, but there are few associated values in the chartevents table.

APACHE scores also appear as free text in the NOTEEVENTS table (for example, "On admission, APACHE II score of 10..."), but again infrequently.

The MIMIC research community is developing code to calculate scores retrospectively which will be shared in the [MIMIC Code Repository](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code).