# MIMIC-III severity score

Tags: mimic-iii

Is there any severity score in the MIMIC-III beyond SOFA? I've found many itemdid with APACHE IV label but I did not retrieve any information in the chartevents. Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might find `itemid`s for various severity scores such as APACHE IV in the hospital data, there will be few associated values. This is because the scores are rarely calculated or recorded by caregivers.

Most of the scores are computed retrospectively by the MIMIC research community. Code for generating scores will be collaboratively developed and shared via the [MIMIC Code Repository](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code).

Answer (score 4):

Adding more severity scores is in the todo list:

[APACHE score or similar #28](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/issues/28):

> We plan to release code for calculating severity
>   scores as soon as we have time to! On the list are SAPS, SOFA, APS III, and
>   SAPS II.

The code to compute the Elixhauser comorbidity measure is available for [MySQL](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/comorbidity/mysql/4-elixhauser.sql) and [Postgres](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/comorbidity/postgres/elixhauser.sql).